# wildcard not working with css width

Tags: css, wildcard

What is the problem of this wildcard?

```
div[id*='Form_Form_EditableTextField'] {
    width:554px !important;
}
```

This works without any problem. Just for debug.

```
#Form_Form_EditableTextField1 {
    width:500px;
}​
```

html

```
  <div class="middleColumn">
    <input id="Form_Form_EditableTextField1" type="text" name="EditableTextField1">
    <input id="Form_Form_EditableTextField2" type="text" name="EditableTextField1">
    </div>​
```

**demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/wLSjY/

Comment: I've always found wildcards such as that messy. Is there a reason for not using a class?

Comment: this code is automatically generated by silverstripe. I have preference by only change the css.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> div[id*='Form_Form_EditableTextField']
> ```

This selects `<div>` elements with matching `id` attributes.  You want to select `<input>` elements.  The following should work:

```
input[id*='Form_Form_EditableTextField']
```